# MBTI quiz - javascript / keep 2 largest results

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to adapt/customize a personality quiz  to find out your personality type. (ex: MBTI test)

It's a quizz with 9 questions (3 x 3 questions) who give a letter result depend you check "A" or "B"
At the end, the current quiz give your profile type with the main three letters.

[Here is the live version on CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/lulostudio/pen/GRdmgrd)

I would like to add one step to this function *showResults()*.
In fact, i would like to keep only the combination of the 2 letters who get the 2 largest percentage/results.
And then show the associated object from this combination of 2 letters (title, description...)

```
    function showResults() {

    type += (s >= n) ? "S" : "N";
    type += (t >= f) ? "T" : "F";

    type2 += (s >= n) ? "S" : "N";
    type2 += (t >= f) ? "T" : "F";
    type2 += (j >= p) ? "J" : "P";
    
    document.querySelector("#type").innerHTML = type;
    document.querySelector("#largest").innerHTML = type2;
    document.querySelector("#type-title").innerHTML = types[type].title;
    document.querySelector("#type-percentage").innerHTML = types[type].percentage;
    document.querySelector("#type-description").innerHTML = types[type].description;
    document.querySelector("#type-site").href = types[type].site;
    document.querySelector("#type-details").classList.remove("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#scroll-down").classList.remove("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#results").classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start to learn how to sum the integer number with js

The sample was like this

const num1 = 5;
const num2 = 3;

// add two numbers
const sum = parseInt(num1 + num2);

// display the sum
console.log('The sum of ' + num1 + ' and ' + num2 + ' is: ' + sum);

After that, try to make if else, to return the biggest possibility

if(mbtiA < mbtiB){
return mbtiB};